# Why is StackOverflow called StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

Well, I just want to know a little bit more about the "why" this was created. The name of StackOverflow was designed because of the related informatic problem, but why this one?

Why not BlueScreen.com?

Or UncaughtErrorException.com?

Or Youdontexistgoaway.com?

Comment: Because AllYourCodingQuestionsAreBelongToUs.com was just too long, and frankly, that meme had been worn out.

Comment: @Jim, for what it's worth, `You don't exist, go away` is an actual error message emitted on some UNIX platforms when the current user is not found in `/etc/passwd`. It was probably not intended to be hostile, and it may not be necessary to edit it out.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It got ninja-edited between the time I loaded the page and saved my edit - I didn't even know it was there until I saw your comment and checked the history.

Comment: It's okay, I know I'm a good ninja. I'll add it back for you ^^

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of the founders of the site [held a poll on his blog](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/help-name-our-website.html) and Stack Overflow was the winner.

Answer (score 6):

Let's ask our friends at Wikipedia :)

> The name for the website was chosen by voting in April 2008 by readers of Coding Horror, Atwood's popular programming blog.